# After editing /etc/paths, printers no longer recognized by macOS after reboot

Tags: macos, printers, system-paths

My printers are not working, I believe as a result of changes I made to my /etc/paths file.

In working with mongoDB, I had to edit the /etc/paths file to include a path for their tutorial: /Users/me/mongodb-macos-x86_64-enterprise-4.4.0/bin
I added this line to the top of my /etc/paths file as instructed, like so:

```
/Users/me/mongodb-macos-x86_64-enterprise-4.4.0/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

After editing the file, I realized I had somehow deleted the path /usr/local/bin

I re-added that line (ultimately in all versions of the existing /etc/paths files on my system: there are multiple save files). For a while my printers worked if I opened the /etc/paths file in terminal and just saved it again. That's not working now (which makes me wonder if the printers working again had anything to do with my attempts).

/Users/me/Library/Printers shows all my expected installed printers. I tried to add that path to the /etc/paths file but that doesn't fix things either.

I assume my mistakes are obvious to someone who knows more about boot order and how and when /etc/paths is called and how I messed up my computer's knowledge/loading of the printers located in /Users/me/Library/Printers.

But, I can't figure out what files I need to fix and how.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but I'd consider it a bad idea to put per-user locations (like anything under /Users/me) in a system-wide configuration file (like /etc/paths). I think it'd be much better to add them to your per-user shell initialization files (~/.bash_profile, etc). If you do need to add to the system paths list, it's also generally best to put them in separate files under /etc/paths.d/

Comment: Thank you for the thought here. Definitely helps little by little with my learning.